# How can I remove a sprite from the screen using pygame?

Tags: sprites, python, pygame

I am having trouble with removing sprites on my screen using pygame. [image: example]

I am killing my sprite with sword.kill which is removing it from an all_sprites group, so it should disappear right?

Here is where i blit my images:

```
def draw(self):
        for sprite in self.all_sprites:
            self.screen.blit(sprite.image, self.camera.apply(sprite))
        pg.display.update()
```

Here is my sword class:

```
class Sword(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y, entity):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = self.game.sword
        #self.image = pg.transform.scale(self.image, (TILESIZE, TILESIZE))
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect.x = x 
        self.rect.y = y 
        if entity.direction == 'down':
            self.image = pg.transform.rotate(self.image, -90)

        def update(self):
            self.kill()
```

And here is where I create my sword object:

```
def get_keys(self):
        self.vx, self.vy = 0, 0
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_LEFT] or keys[pg.K_a]:
            self.game.walk_sound.play(-1)
            now = pg.time.get_ticks()
            self.vx = -200
            self.direction = 'left'
            if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
               self.last_update = now
               try:
                    self.game.player_img = self.game.walkleft[self.frame]
                    self.frame += 1
               except IndexError:
                    self.frame = 0
            self.swing = False
        elif keys[pg.K_RIGHT] or keys[pg.K_d]:
            self.game.walk_sound.play(-1)
            now = pg.time.get_ticks()
            self.vx = 200
            self.direction = 'right'
            if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
               self.last_update = now
               try:
                    self.game.player_img = self.game.walkright[self.frame]
                    self.frame += 1
               except IndexError:
                    self.frame = 0
            self.swing = False
        elif keys[pg.K_UP] or keys[pg.K_w]:
            self.game.walk_sound.play(-1)
            now = pg.time.get_ticks()
            self.vy = -200
            self.direction = 'up'
            if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
               self.last_update = now
               try:
                    self.game.player_img = self.game.walkup[self.frame]
                    self.frame += 1
               except IndexError:
                    self.frame = 0
            self.swing = False
        elif keys[pg.K_DOWN] or keys[pg.K_s]:

            self.game.walk_sound.play(-1)
            now = pg.time.get_ticks()
            self.direction = 'down'
            self.vy = 200
            if now - self.last_update > self.frame_rate:
               self.last_update = now
               try:
                    self.game.player_img = self.game.walkdown[self.frame]
                    self.frame += 1
               except IndexError:
                    self.frame = 0
            self.swing = False
        elif keys[pg.K_SPACE]:
            self.attack = True
            if self.direction == 'down':
                print(self.rect.centery)
                self.sword = Sword(self.game, self.rect.centerx-7, self.rect.bottom, self)
        elif self.vx != 0 and self.vy != 0:
            self.vx *= 0.7071
            self.vy *= 0.7071
            self.swing = False
        elif keys[pg.K_t]:
            self.x = 1 * TILESIZE
            self.y = 1 * TILESIZE
            self.swing = False
        elif self.attack and not keys[pg.K_SPACE]:
            self.sword.update()
            self.attack = False
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: did you try to `self.sword = None` after you used it?

Comment: @Vaillancourt I set self.attack at the very bottom, I accidentally didn’t copy that in.  I did try self.sword = None, but it does not change anything

Comment: @Vaillancourt if you want to test all the code, the github is https://github.com/WrenVin/ZeldaGame on branch MapWork